# What happens if a file is edited while being compressed by zip?

Tags: backup, zip

I ask this question to know how careful I need to be about accessing and editing files while I am running a backup on my Linux machine.  What happens to the compression process (specifically zip) or the files if I open or edit them while they are being compressed?

Update:  Just barely I removed a file while it was being zipped.  Zip quit working on that file immediately and warned me that the file's size changed.

Comment: as far as i know, linux normally don't lock files being edited. so you get the file content till the last save before the zip process reads it.

Comment: So, neither the file nor the zip process gets messed up?

Comment: i never got things messed up when doing backup and file is open. and actually it is very difficult to close all files before going for a backup in linux.

Comment: @bansi That will depend on the application accessing the files. If you e.g. try to zip up a mysql or postgres database while it's in use/being written to, you most likely end up with a backup containing a corrupt database.

Comment: @nos I don't think zip database file is a good way of making backup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linux uses advisory locks, so nothing actually prevents you from modifying a file that's being read/written by another process. If your programs lock the files they are working on, one of the two will complain about the file being opened by some other program.

What usually happens when a file is concurrently modified is data corruption.
Anyhow, this is quite rare, because files are seldom modified. What most commonly happens is that the original file is removed/truncated, and a new one is added in its place.
When a file is removed, Linux assigns a new inode to the new file, so, the old file remains accessible by its previous inode.
When a file is truncated, it should keep the same inode (I'm unsure, though). Anyway, if some other process was accessing the file, it will get an I/O error, because it was at location X, and when it tries to read location X+1 it gets an error, because the file has now a 0 length, a X+1 is out of range. By examining the situation, a program can determine that the size of the file has changed, which means it's being concurrently modified.

To summarize, on Linux, synchronization of I/O operations is responsibility of the single processes, which can ask the OS for a help, but they are not forced to.